# How to correctly position vertical oriented text on a div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table made by divs on bootstrap. I want on the first column the text be vertical (orientation -90deg). I was able to successfully turn the text but, if the the text is longer, it looses the position.

It always show up like on this screenshot: https://ibb.co/2s8dzyZ

I have tried several techniques found on the web but none seems to solve my problem.

```css
.horizontal-pricing {
  min-height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.verticaltext {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right, top;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: right, top;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right, top;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #3c99ef;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container purple-accent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Light 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Light 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Professional 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Professional 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Performance 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Performance 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want the text be vertically aligned on the middle of the white box and 20px from the left side.

Comment: Protip: `col-md-8` is redundant in `col-sm-8 col-md-8`.

Comment: you have a lot of <div><div>Something</div></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`writing-mode`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

```css
.verticaltext {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container purple-accent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Light 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Light 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Professional 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Professional 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Performance 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Performance 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div>
          <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZNNEeB)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to have `<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"><div>` closed without content, and then have  `<div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">`closed after `<div class="verticaltext">Light 1</div>` and after that already close the row??

```
<div class="container purple-accent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">  

//THINK ABOUT THIS PART OUF YOUR CODE
<div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div>
          <div class="verticaltext">Light 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

By your formatting I think this would be more of what you want:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="pricing-box horizontal-pricing">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <div class="verticaltext">Light 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    more div's inside row here
```